# shutil.rmtree() error when trying to remove NFS-mounted directory

Tags: python-3.x, nfs

Attempting to execute `shutil.rmtree(path)` on a directory managed by NFS consistently fails. Below you can see that `os.rmdir(path)` within `shutil.rmtree(path)` causes the exception. Is there a more robust way for me to achieve the expected result?

It appears that it removes all of the files, yet a hidden `.nfs` file remains in the directory for a short amount of time. I'm guessing that the process from which I'm calling `rmtree` has an open file handle to one of the files inside the directory, which, when deleted, apparently causes NFS to write a new hidden [file](https://uisapp2.iu.edu/confluence-prd/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=123962105). That would cause `os.rmdir` to fail on attempting to remove a non-empty directory.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/pre3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 484, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/me/pre3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 482, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty:
```

NFS details:

```
$ nfsstat -m
/home/me/nfs from XXX.YYY.ZZZ:/mnt/path/to/nfs
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=50,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=REDACTED,mountvers=3,mountport=832,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=REDACTED
```

I'm using Python 3.6.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You have correctly identified a common reason that `rm -r` on an NFS-mounted directory will fail.  The question for you is what process has the file open, and why. You can run `fuser` on the .nfs file to see what process has it open. You can also look at the file to see what file it is. Then you can begin deciding how to cause the file to be closed so that you can succeed in removing the directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the python `logging` module is logging to the target output directory, it will maintain an open file. A workaround is to call `logging.shutdown()` first, then called `shutil.rmtree(path)`. This is not a general answer to the broader question, however.

Comment: For me it was due to not closing a database connection

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining an error handler function to be passed to the `onerror` arg for `shutil.rmtree`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

```py
def handle_rmtree_err(function, path, excinfo):
    ...
```

```py
shutil.rmtree(my_path, onerror=handle_rmtree_err)
```

There are all sorts of reasons why a process may be holding onto a file, so I can't tell you what the error handler should do exactly.

If you haven't figured out what is holding onto the file, try `$ lsof | grep .nfsXXXX`.

If all else fails you could `time.sleep(secs)` and retry `shutil.rmtree`.